# Is it possible to use .tk_setPalette() on the content of only one Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a root with several frames, each of them has labels.

1. I set the foreground and background for root,
2. then would like to have a specific foreground and background for all children of **one** selected frame.

I did not manage to make the change for one frame only, the change propagates to all of them.

The following code is an example.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        # this frame content will be modified
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.a = tk.Label(self.frame, text="hello world", font=("Arial", 100))
        self.a.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # this frame content will not change
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.a2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="bazinga", font=("Arial", 100))
        self.a2.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.root.bind('q', self.toggle)

    def toggle(self, event):
        # go through all children (= Labels) of the first frame
        for children in self.frame.children.values():
            children.tk_setPalette(background="black", foreground="blue")
            children.configure()

app = MyApp()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Upon the call, colors are not set:

[image]

When pressing `q` I expected to go though the labels in `self.frame` only and have the upper label colors change. This is not the case:

[image]

What can I do to update the colors of the children of one selected frame only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the `tk_setPalette` method for this.  Instead use the [`configure` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.configure-method):

```
children.configure(background="black", foreground="blue")
```

Note too that you can write the above more concisely if you want:

```
children.config(bg="black", fg="blue")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I was using `tk_setPalette` because this is the only solution I found if I want to set the foreground and background of `self.root`: `.configure()` raises an exception (-foreground parameter not known). Am I doing something wrong or does `.configure()` only works on widgets and not on the root?

Comment: @WoJ - No, `.configure` works with `root`.  The problem is that you cannot set the foreground color of `root` because there is no foreground to set.  You can set its background though: `root.config(bg="blue")`.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks. How should I set the default foreground color for Labels then? I know I can `.configure()` them one by one but is `tk_setPalette` the way to handle the defaults (inherited by the labels)?

Comment: Not sure, but I think the best you can do is to inline it:  `tk.Label(root, text="blah", font=("Arial", 100)), fg="blue")`.  Although you may want to research the [`ttk` module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html), which allows you to create sytle classes the affect multiple widgets at once.